# Javascript countdown using for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have attempted using the for loop to display my Countdown, but I don't know where I am getting it wrong. Is there a simpler way to display the countdown for each row using vanilla javascript?

My Table Below:

```js
var exp = document.getElementById('tab').getElementsByClassName('exp1');
    
    var x = document.getElementById('tab').getElementsByClassName('demo');
    
    var   now = new Date();
    function test(){
    
    for (i = 0; i<exp.length; i++){
    var  e = new Date( exp[i].innerHTML);
    var  timeDiff = e.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours   = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days    = Math.floor(hours   / 24);
    hours %=24;
    minutes %=60;
    seconds %=60;
    var timer = setTimeout('test()', 1000);   
    }
    
    for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    x[i].innerHTML = days  + " " +  hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
    }
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <body> 
    <table style="width:50%" id= "tab">
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Exp</th>
    <th>Count Down</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td> A</td>
         <td class = 'exp1'> 09/08/2019</td>
         <td class = 'demo'> </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td> B</td>
         <td class = 'exp1'> 09/08/2020</td>
         <td class = 'demo'> </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Here's a pretty good example of what you're trying to accomplish [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp)

Comment: change `var timer = setTimeout('test()', 1000);` to `var timer = setTimeout(test, 1000);`

Comment: `setTimeout(test, 1000)`  pass the function, not the result of calling the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done most of the things right.. using setInterval and a minor modification will make this work

```js
var exp = document.getElementById('tab').getElementsByClassName('exp1');

var x = document.getElementById('tab').getElementsByClassName('demo');


function test(){
  var   now = new Date();
  for (i = 0; i<exp.length; i++){
    var  e = new Date( exp[i].innerHTML);
    var  timeDiff = e.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours   = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days    = Math.floor(hours   / 24);
    hours %=24;
    minutes %=60;
    seconds %=60;
    x[i].innerHTML =  days  + "d " +  hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds +"s";
  //var timer = setTimeout('test()', 1000);   
  }

  //for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
  //x[i].innerHTML = days  + " " +  hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
  //}
}
setInterval(function(){ test();; }, 1000);
```

```html
<html>
<body> 
<table style="width:100%" id= "tab">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Exp</th>
<th>Count Down</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
     <td> A</td>
     <td class = 'exp1'> 10/13/2018</td>
     <td class = 'demo'> </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> B</td>
     <td class = 'exp1'> 09/08/2020</td>
     <td class = 'demo'> </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, there's no first time call to `test()`. So either you forgot to write it in the question or you don't have it in the code. Someone needs to call `test()` for the first time before that forever loop with `setTimeout` begins.

I have added a snippet of code that you can run, it has the HTML you pasted as well as the JavaScript. The only difference is that I called `test()` after your `var now` to get it started.

A couple of things:

- I moved the `setTimeout` out of the `for loop` since putting it there would mean that you'd call it with every iteration instead of every second. Also, you can't have the `now` variable as a global value, you need to get it every time you want to calculate the difference inside the function. If you look into the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you'll see:

> Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in time. Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.
>   var date1 = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
>   // Sun Dec 17 1995 03:24:00 GMT...

That means that when you create the Date, it represents a **single moment in time**, it's like if you took a snapshot of that time and kept it there, frozen.

- The second problem comes with how you are displaying the info. If you have variables that you are changing within that **for loop** scope, once you leave that iteration, the values are gone forever. If you only display that info (**days, minutes, hours, days**) after your `for loop`, then you will have the last value saved into those variables. Not exactly what you are looking for. To fix that all you have to do is move that `x[i].innerHTML = days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";` to the same loop as where you are calculating the values.
- As a side note, you could checkout `setInterval()` since it's pretty much what you want.

```js
var exp = document.getElementById('tab').getElementsByClassName('exp1');
var x = document.getElementById('tab').getElementsByClassName('demo');
test();

function test() {
  var now = new Date();
  for (i = 0; i < exp.length; i++) {
    var e = new Date(exp[i].innerHTML);
    var timeDiff = e.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    x[i].innerHTML = days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
  }

  var timer = setTimeout("test()", 1000);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table style="width:50%" id="tab">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Exp</th>
      <th>Count Down</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> A</td>
      <td class='exp1'> 09/08/2019</td>
      <td class='demo'> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> B</td>
      <td class='exp1'> 09/08/2020</td>
      <td class='demo'> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```